# How to exclude the first 10 sheets from a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script here loops through the sheet names and changes the names to match the value in A1. How can I exclude the first 10 sheet names from the execution instead of providing the specific sheet names to be excluded?

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();

  // Array holding the names of the sheets to exclude from the execution
  var exclude =["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3","Article","Frontpage","Logos","Sheet4","Sheet5","Sheet6","Sheet10"];

for(var s in allsheets){
var sheet = allsheets[s];
var oldName = sheet.getName();
var newName = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
if (newName.toString().length>0 && newName !== oldName) {
sheet.setName(newName);

// Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1) continue;
  }

} // end of loop

} // end of function
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

As `getSheets()` method returns an `Array` of `Sheet` instances, you have access to every method designed for iterating over arrays and thus do not need `for...in` (if want to be able to `break` out of the loop or use `continue` statement, use `for...of` instead).

**Use slice()**

The simplest would be using `slice` method - it returns a partial copy of the array without modifying the original. The method call accepts two arguments, both optional:

1. 0-based start index
2. 0-based end index (end is exclusive)

```js
var arr = ['Sh1', 'Sh2', 'Sh3', 'Sh4', 'Sh5', 'Sh6', 'Sh7', 'Sh8', 'Sh9', 'Sh10', 'Sh11', 'Sh12'];
var relevantSheets = arr.slice(10); //simply slice everything after sheet 10
console.log(relevantSheets); //should log [Sh11, Sh12]
```

**Use splice()**

`splice()` method is very similar to the first one, but allows to "permanently" exclude elements from the array. Just configure it to remove first N elements and do not replace them:

```js
var arr = ['Sh1', 'Sh2', 'Sh3', 'Sh4', 'Sh5', 'Sh6', 'Sh7', 'Sh8', 'Sh9', 'Sh10', 'Sh11', 'Sh12'];
arr.splice(0, 10); //0-based start and end indices (end is exclusive);
console.log(arr); //should log [Sh11, Sh12]
```

Refer to documentation for an in-depth explanation. In short, this method accepts an indefinite amount of arguments:

1. **Required:** 0-based index to start from
2. **Optional:** 0-based index to end before (if not provided or greater than length of the `Array` the method is called on, removes every element starting from start index)
3. **Optional:** Comma separated list of elements to replace removed items

> Note that the method mutates (changes) the original array.

**Use forEach()**

A more modern approach if you need some side-effects to happen *for each* element, is using `forEach` method and checking if `index` is greater than `10` (array indices are 0-based, hence `9` in sample):

```js
var arr = ['Sh1', 'Sh2', 'Sh3', 'Sh4', 'Sh5', 'Sh6', 'Sh7', 'Sh8', 'Sh9', 'Sh10', 'Sh11', 'Sh12'];

var res = [];

arr.forEach(function(element, index) {
  if (index > 9) {
    res.push(element); //push to test Array;
    //iterable code goes here;
  }
});

console.log(res); //should log ['Sh11','Sh12']
```

Note that `forEach` method callback function accepts three arguments:

1. **Required:** Array element to iterate over;
2. **Optional:** 0-based index of element currently looped over;
3. **Optional:** Array over which the loop iterates;

Please refer to documentation to better understand how this `Array` method works. Also, refrain from using a `for...in` loop in contexts where order of iteration is relevant.

**Notes**

1. You do not need to stop iteration after there are no more
   `Sheet` instances in an `Array` - the loop will terminate upon finishing iterating over the last element.

**References**

1. `slice()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
2. `forEach()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
3. `splice()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
4. `getSheets()` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
5. `for...of` [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `for(var s in allsheets){`

user `for(var s=10;i<allsheets.length;i++) {`

Comment: Thanks for the extensive replies.Cooper, your answer which is preferable for me but it's throwing a "ReferenceError: "s" is not defined. (line 12, file "Code")error" highlighting the following line var sheet = allsheets[s]; As regards the other second reply, I'm not able to use var arr because it requires that I list them. The array changes dynamically. Help fix the error the reference error.

Comment: I changed the line that threw an error var sheet = allsheets[s] to var sheet = allsheets[i];. Thanks for the help Cooper and Oleg.

Comment: I changed the I to s.

Comment: Looks like you also have to change all references of i to `for(var s=10;s<allsheets.length;s++)` or just `for(var i=10;i<allsheets.length;i++) {`  then followed by `var sheet = allsheets[s];` or `var sheet = allsheets[i];` respectively. Maintaining the s or i all through works.